# Dynamic web form pulling info from database

Tags: asp.net, forms

complete newbie here so apologies in advance! I don't even know if it's possible to do this but hoping someone can help me!

I'm creating a website for an event and would like to create an RSVP form that pulls information from a database and displays it on the page, people can then update the info and then it saves it back in the database.

For example, someone goes onto the site and either has a password to enter or selects their family name from a dropdown box, then every person under that family would be displayed e.g. someone selects The Smith Family (or enters the unique password given to The Smith's) and then Mum, Dad, Child 1, Child 2, Child 3 is displayed. The user can then select that Mum, Child 1 and Child 2 are attending but Dad and Child 3 cannot attend. For the ones that are attending the user can enter their meal choices and any dietary requirements, and then press save and it either shoots an email to the organiser or saves in the database.

Is this possible? I wouldn't even know where to start! Someone I mentioned it to started talking about ASP but I've not worked with ASP before so any help would be gratefully received!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need a membership system with profiles.

Comment: Thanks @IrishChieftain - how would I go about designing something like that?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but I think if you have not worked with ASP or any web framework it could be very challenging trying to learn and create a web app with the requeriments you mentioned. I recommend you use a form service like Zoho integrated with Wordpress engine. However if you have some background in programming, the time and resources to learn and build a web app use ASP MVC framework, check [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started)

Comment: @alejandrozuleta thanks! That's helpful